# Pandas GROUPBY inside np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm getting error with code below:

`np.where(df['A'].groupby([df['B'], df['B_1']]).sum() > 0, 1, 0)`

**error:** `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2013,) (1353,) ()`

Is it possible to do pandas `groupby` inside `np.where` ?

What is the best way to do this?

I would like to `sum` a column `df[A]` where column `df[B]` and `df[B_1]`

**formula in excel:**

`=IF($J3=$C3,IF(SUMIFS($S:$S,$A:$A,$A3,$C:$C,$C3)>0,1,0),"")`

**formula in python:**

`df['C'] = np.where(df['B_1'] == df['B'], np.where(df['competing'].groupby([df['company_id'], df['company_id.1']]).sum() > 0, 1, 0), None)`

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output this question.

Comment: your formula and your error show different codes. The error on top looks like it makes sense but the 'formula in python' would make sense to raise an error due shape mismatch

Comment: It looks like your output is binary.  In that case, you *don't* need `numpy.where`, instead use `astype` int.  It also looks like you need `transform`

Comment: Any time you have problems in `np.where`, look at the arguments by themselves.  In this case `df['A'].groupby([df['B'], df['B_1']]).sum() > 0`.  Python runs that first, and then feeds it to `where`.  Also keep in mind that `where` is expecting a numpy array (or will do a `np.asarray()` on the input first).

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the response. `transform` did the trick. see answer from Parfait below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel's `SUMIFS` return inline aggregates based on conditions where return values are the same length as input values (i.e., before and after calculation).

To achieve a similar result, consider pandas' [`groupby().transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) that also returns inline aggregates where returned column is same length as input column(s). Running `groupby()` by itself collapses records to those groupings returning a different length of values.

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['B_1'] == df['B'], 
                   np.where(df.groupby(['company_id', 'company_id.1'])['competing'].transform('sum') > 0, 1, 0),
                   np.nan)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and tip -  very helpful and have learnt something new.

Comment: @Parfait can you please have a look into my question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083576/pandas-row-filters-and-and-division-from-specific-rows-and-columns]